# Performing join operation on 3 tables using knexjs - psql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js

i'm new to psql and knexjs, i have three tables like

**userTable**,

```
id,
phone_number,
```

**bankDetailsTable**,

```
id,
user_id,
bank_name,
acc_api_key,
```

**socialMediaTable**.

```
id,
user_id,
media_channel_name,
channel_api_key,
```

i want the result like this

```
[{
id:1, 
phone_number:'42223424234', 
bankDetails:[
  {
    user_id:1, 
    bank_name:'abc bank', 
    acc_api_key: 'cQ54B325KB2345434'
  },
 {
    user_id:1, 
    bank_name:'cBD bank', 
    acc_api_key: 'JJJSIDD98ASD0AS'
  },
 {
    user_id:1, 
    bank_name:'EFG bank', 
    acc_api_key: '789FAF8AFFYDF9E'
  }
],
socialMedia:[
  {
    user_id:1, 
    media_channel_name:'whatsapp', 
    channel_api_key: '45n2q35oi5'
  },
 {
    user_id:1, 
    media_channel_name:'facebook', 
    channel_api_key: 'q2j3i355'
  }
]
},
{
id:2, 
phone_number:'72372373828382', 
bankDetails:[
 {
    user_id:2, 
    bank_name:'eere bank', 
    acc_api_key: 'erereac'
  },
{
    user_id:2, 
    bank_name:'iff bank', 
    acc_api_key: '789FAF8AFFYDF9E'
  }
],
socialMedia:[{
    user_id:2, 
    media_channel_name:'instagram', 
    channel_api_key: '09e8q232'
  }
]
}]
```

I tried this query, but it won't work as expected,

```
 let data = await userModel.query()
        .leftJoin('bank_details', 'user.id', '=', 'bank_details.user_id')
        .leftJoin('social_media', 'user.id', '=', 'social_media.user_id')
        .select("*")
```

below is the details on schema and models, where i need to fetch the records like above based on the created_date should be greater than particular date

**userTable**

```
import { Model } from 'objection';

class userModel extends Model {

  public id!: number;
  public name!: string;
  public phone_number!: string;
  public created_at!: string;
  public updated_at!: string;

  static get tableName(): string {
    return 'user';
  }

  static get jsonSchema(): schema {
    return {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        id: { type: 'integer' },
        name: { type: 'string' },
        phone_number: { type: 'string' },
        member_id: { type: 'string' },
        created_at: { type: 'string' },
        updated_at: { type: 'string' },
      },
    };
  }
}

export default userModel;
```

**bankDetailsTable**

```
import { Model } from 'objection';

class bankDetailsModel extends Model {

  public id!: number;
  public bank_name!: string;
  public acc_api_key!: string;
  public user_id!: number;
  public created_at!: string;
  public updated_at!: string;

  static get tableName(): string {
    return 'bank_details';
  }

  static get jsonSchema(): schema {
    return {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        id: { type: 'integer' },
        bank_name: { type: 'string' },
        acc_api_key: { type: 'string' },
        user_id: { type: 'integer' },
        created_at: { type: 'string' },
        updated_at: { type: 'string' },
      },
    };
  }
}

export default bankDetailsModel;
```

**socialMediaTable**

```
import { Model } from 'objection';

class socialMediaModel extends Model {

  public id!: number;
  public media_channel_name!: string;
  public channel_api_key!: string;
  public user_id!: number;
  public created_at!: string;
  public updated_at!: string;

  static get tableName(): string {
    return 'social_media';
  }

  static get jsonSchema(): schema {
    return {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        id: { type: 'integer' },
        media_channel_name: { type: 'string' },
        channel_api_key: { type: 'string' },
        user_id: { type: 'integer' },
        created_at: { type: 'string' },
        updated_at: { type: 'string' },
      },
    };
  }
}

export default socialMediaModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't do `select *` you have two tables have same column name `user_id` so basically select the columns you need

```
`select('user.id', 'bank_details.bank_name', 'social_media.media_channel_name' 'bank_name', 'year')`
```

Comment: it doesn't return the bank details and social media in array in matching user.id with user_id

Comment: `select *` it returns the user table rows alongside the joined tables